# Azure Service Fabric remoting framework exception handling

Tags: exception, azure-service-fabric, remoting

I have an Azure Service Fabric stateless service that a client connects to using remoting via ServiceProxy and I am trying to catch exceptions raised in the service within the client. The online documentation says:

> The remoting framework propagates exceptions thrown at the service to
>   the client. So exception-handling logic at the client by using
>   ServiceProxy can directly handle exceptions that the service throws.

However, all I seem to get is a System.Exception with some other error message inside such as:

> Exception of type
>   'ExceptionServiceCommon.Exceptions.MyCustomException' was thrown.

I am using a seriously back-to-the-bone implementation in order to solve this for a problem in a more complex case.

The service code is:

```
internal sealed class ExceptionService : StatelessService, IException
{
    public ExceptionService(StatelessServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
    { }

    public Task ThrowException()
    {
        throw new MyCustomException();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(initParams => this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(initParams))
        };
    }
}
```

The interface and exception defined in a common assembly are:

```
public interface IException : IService
{
    Task ThrowException();
}

[Serializable]
public class MyCustomException : Exception
{
    public MyCustomException()
    { }

    public MyCustomException(string message)
        : base(message) { }

    public MyCustomException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    { }

    protected MyCustomException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
        : base(info, context)
    {
    }
}
```

The code in the client (console application) is:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = ServiceProxy.Create<IException>(new Uri("fabric:/ExceptionApplication/ExceptionService"));

        try
        {
            client.ThrowException().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        }
        catch (MyCustomException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("My Custom Exception");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plain old Exception");
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

MyCustomException never gets caught, only Exception.

Comment: I've yet to play woth this yet... However I don't imagine it could. How would your, er, calling assembly have references to the exception types (classes) thrown in the remote? I would love to be proved wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not picking up the exception on the client side is that it is wrapped in an `AggregateException`. Simply ensure you catch that in your try/catch and then [handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.handle(v=vs.110).aspx) your custom exception type.

```cs
    public void Fail()
    {
        var faultyService = ServiceProxy.Create<IException>(
            new Uri("fabric:/ExceptionApplication/ExceptionService"));

        try
        {
            faultyService.ThrowException().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (CustomException cex)
        {
            // Will never be hit                
        }
        catch (AggregateException aex)
        {
            aex.Handle(ex =>
            {
                var cex = ex as CustomException;
                if (cex != null)
                {
                    // Will be hit by your code
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Will never be hit
        }
    }
```